# Machine Learning Projection - Error:"Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead"

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning

I've trained the model. It works well. It works if I do single line inputs. I'm now trying to do looping across my data to get the prediction for 60k+ items.

Input is text stored in a dataframe column (df)

Example `input = "Tomi Lahren: 'Oppression Olympics' should not be topic of conversation right now."` (as seen below).

How do I transform this? It's being passed into the loop as a string.

```
#------ Loop:
for each in df['short_description'].head(5):
       
    test_features=transformer.transform([each])
    get_top_k_predictions(model,each,2)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=Tomi Lahren: 'Oppression Olympics' should not be topic of conversation right now.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

---

---

Here are the transform def's:
'''

```
def train_model(df,field="text_desc",feature_rep="binary",top_k=3):

logging.info("Starting model training...")

# GET A TRAIN TEST SPLIT (set seed for consistent results)
training_data, testing_data = train_test_split(df,random_state = 2000,)

# GET LABELS
Y_train=training_data['category'].values
Y_test=testing_data['category'].values
 
# GET FEATURES
X_train,X_test,feature_transformer=extract_features(df,field,training_data,testing_data,type=feature_rep)

# INIT LOGISTIC REGRESSION CLASSIFIER
logging.info("Training a Logistic Regression Model...")
scikit_log_reg = LogisticRegression(verbose=1, solver='liblinear',random_state=0, C=5, penalty='l2',max_iter=1000)
model=scikit_log_reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)

# GET TOP K PREDICTIONS
preds=get_top_k_predictions(model,X_test,top_k)

# GET PREDICTED VALUES AND GROUND TRUTH INTO A LIST OF LISTS - for ease of evaluation
eval_items=collect_preds(Y_test,preds)

# GET EVALUATION NUMBERS ON TEST SET -- HOW DID WE DO?
logging.info("Starting evaluation...")
accuracy=compute_accuracy(eval_items)
mrr_at_k=compute_mrr_at_k(eval_items)

logging.info("Done training and evaluation.")

return model,feature_transformer,accuracy,mrr_at_k
```

'''

---

this works as a 1-line entry:

'''
test_features=transformer.transform(["George Aref Nader... child pornography"])

```
get_top_k_predictions(model,test_features,2)'''
```

my intention is to take a list and create the appropriate predictions.
There seems to be an issue with instantiating the item passed as a variable.

Imports:

```
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer

import numpy as np
import logging
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import openpyxl
import time
import glob
import shutil
import nltk, re, pprint
from nltk import word_tokenize
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime
from time import process_time
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, is there a reason that you're calling `transformer.transform([each])` instead of `transformer.transform(each)`?

Comment: The change created an error:
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Comment: At least include the definition of the variable `transformer`

Comment: First of all, it's difficult to read code in a comment; please edit your response into your question rather than responding in a comment. Second, your comment doesn't answer my question. What I'm looking for is the first line where you mention transformer; this will either be a line of the form `transformer = _____` or an `import` statement with transformer in it somewhere.

Comment: I suspect that it's a line of the form `from sklearn.____ import ____`

Comment: thank you for your help. I'll keep researching... I'll post the solution here.

Comment: Your latest edit comes a bit closer to explaining things... my best guess is that your `transformer` is the `feature_transformer` output of the `train_model` function, and `feature_transformer` is in turn one of the outputs of `extract_feature`. With that said, it looks like you imported some module that has the `extract_feature` method that you're using. It would help to be able to look at the documentation for that method.

Comment: TL;DR: I think the best way for you to help out any potential answerers is to paste in all of your `import` statements (likely at the beginning of your script or .py file).